# Familiarity with subject related literature as a skill in CV

Tags: resume

I'm currently studying Computer Science at University, and I'm going to apply for an intern position at a few companies. Reviewers will probably be flooded by similarly looking CV and resumes (considering most of the students in my city will complete same course) so every bit of distinction may be important.

I would like to include fact that I read domain specific literature in English. Given that I'm from Poland, it seems far more useful information for possible employer than ambiguous "advanced level" of language abilities (Sadly I don't have any certificates). And such literature can also speak for itself. It is not much, but naming one or two titles shows that I probably know a little bit more than basic we have learned at our course. Or it can show that my knowledge focuses on things they don't need which is also valuable information.

My problem is, that I'm not sure whether this is important enough, and if this doesn't look silly. I have also problems with wording this in a nice and informative way. I currently have this phrases in my CV:

> - Polish - mother tongue
> - English - advanced level, including domain    specific language

---

> - Familiarity with object-oriented programing, including GoF’s “Design Patterns”, or R. Martin’s “Clean Code”

First doesn't really say what I want to say, and second is a little bit odd.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to make it look better. Or whether I should include it at all.

Comment: You are from Poland. But, what are the locations of the internships?

Comment: Are you confident in answering technical questions/having discussions in English? That will be more important to employers than what books you've read, and whether you read the English language-edition or a translation.

Comment: @scaaahu Location is Poland too.

Comment: @Brandin I have less experience with speaking (I don't have that many occasions to talk in English), but generally yes, I can answer any question concerning my domain in English. In some aspects it is even easier. I'm little bit familiar with English terms for example.
However writing phrase like "I can discuss technical problems in English" seems to be too general, it still just my opinion.

Comment: To show how good your english is I can recommend expressing it with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages

Comment: Here in Edinburgh there are groups that spend half the evening speaking one language and the other half speaking a different language (so people have a chance of learning a different language and speaking it). Is there something similar where you live?

Comment: @Ed Heal Not really. Most people know English from school, many are able to use it with ease. However usually there is no reason to use other than Polish, as there aren't many people from aboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Polish - mother tongue

If you are applying in Poland - take this off your resume.

> English - advanced level, including domain specific language

This is fine to leave on, pinpoint it down more, ex.

```
Advanced Level English, Domain Specific Languages in English
```

> Familiarity with object-oriented programing, including GoF’s “Design Patterns”, or R. Martin’s “Clean Code”

You say 'Familiarity' that's usually not a good thing to have, if you are comfortable being asked on the stuff about it just design the resume part to show that. Then if you get an interview you can explain and discuss it and why it's important but you don't want to be 'red-flagged' for having something on the resume just to stand out that you may not actually know.

ex.

```
Object Oriented Programming, GoF's "Design Patterns", Martin's "Clean Code"
```

Comment: Many thanks.
This particular part about Polish is there because company I'm applying to is using one system for many countries. They expect CV's to be in English, and presented job offers are from dozens of countries. From that perspective it seems good to clarify that I can speak Polish.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense, a good thing to mention. If language is pertinent to the job then yes by all means mention all your languages. I would list more professionally though like "Languages: Polish (native), English (fluent)" type of a thing.